# Write to Internet Explorer javascript console with vba in excel

Tags: javascript, ajax, excel, vba, http

i'm trying to send a simple http post request. It works perfectly fine if I send it via the Internet Explorer console using ajax, but i'm having problems doing it in VBA. 
I've identified that the problem is the proxy server of the company i'm working at. It only allows configured software to access the internet. So my VBA script gets blocked, but everything works fine with Internet Explorer. 
Is there anyway I can simply write directly into the Internet Explorer Console and send the http post request from there via ajax?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: you mean controlled from excel? Unless there's some COM object that lets you automate IE, then no. And it's unlikely, due to browser security restrictions, that you could pull the response data out into Excel either. If you have a genuine business need to do this, and Excel is really the best medium for doing this work (often in my experience it's just a workaround to avoid having a developer write a proper application), then you probably need to make a request to your IT service to make an exception to this rule to allow your spreadsheet to connect to the proxy.

Comment: It's also possible that you already can do this, but simply your proxy is returning a 407 ("Proxy Authentication Required") response? Which means you just need to be supplying the correct proxy credentials as part of the HTTP request and it will work. Depending how the proxy is configured there are different ways to do this - have a google around.

Comment: Thank you for your response @ADyson. So there's no way to send data to the IE console. Is there a way to perform an http post with a CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") in vba?
I have no problem accessing the internet through that. 
Normally I use CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1") for that, but there the proxy server prevents my from getting out of the company Intranet. Inside it works perfectly fine to access our local servers like MS Sharepoint. Also I don't need the direct response. I only need it to access the next website to parse data from it.

Comment: Did you check what I mentioned about proxy credentials? I don't know about the InternetExplorer.Application object in any detail, you'd have to read the documentation (if there is any!)

Comment: yes, I did. but IT isn't very helpfull in telling me how to configure my script for the proxy server. Also this script is a one time thing, so not worth putting too much hassle into it. I'm just trying to collect material data for special Simulations from some websites and i'm too lazy to copy paste it all into excel.

Comment: you can probably check in your IE settings how it's configured to access the proxy, and try and replicate that. But yeah it might just be easier to copy it, sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**not meant as an answer**

this is taken from the object browser

`navigate method` of the InternetExplorer object

```
Sub Navigate(URL As String, [Flags], [TargetFrameName], [PostData], [Headers])
Member of SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Navigates to a URL or file.
```

so maybe this object might work `CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`

the microsoft site mentions that POST method is used if data is in the *PostData* argument, otherwise the GET method is used

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752093(v=vs.85).aspx

PS: the OP found this call that solved the problem with calling AJAX, as per comment from OP

```
IE.document.parentWindow.execScript("javascript_code()", "JavaScript")
```

quick example ...

```
IE.Document.parentWindow.execScript "alert('Arbitrary javascript code')", "javascript"
```

Comment: Thank you! That was what I was looking for. Unfortunately I couldn't get it to work. I don't know why. But then I discovered this nice piece of code: Call IE.document.parentWindow.execScript("javascript_code()", "JavaScript") and it worked like a charm with my ajax call. So all problems solved now.